# Unknown props on direct copy of example form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to get the basic form example for redux form (http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/simple/) working. I've copied the code and trimmed it down to just one input, like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const { DOM: { input, select, textarea } } = React;

console.log('input', input);

const SimpleForm = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = props;
  console.log('props', props);
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <div>
          <Field id="firstName" name="firstName" component={input} type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
        <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'simple',  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SimpleForm);
```

This unfortunately results in:

```
Warning: Unknown props `input`, `meta` on <input> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see react-unknown-prop
        in input (created by bound createElement)
        in bound createElement (created by ConnectedField)
        in ConnectedField (created by Connect(ConnectedField))
        in Connect(ConnectedField) (created by Field)
        in Field (created by SimpleForm)
        in div (created by SimpleForm)
        in div (created by SimpleForm)
        in form (created by SimpleForm)
        in SimpleForm (created by Form(SimpleForm))
        in Form(SimpleForm) (created by Connect(Form(SimpleForm)))
        in Connect(Form(SimpleForm)) (created by ReduxForm)
        in ReduxForm (created by CreateEntityPage)
        in div (created by Paper)
        in Paper (created by CreateEntityPage)
        in div (created by CreateEntityPage)
        in CreateEntityPage (created by RouterContext)
        in main (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in MuiThemeProvider (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in App (created by Connect(App))
        in Connect(App) (created by RouterContext)
        in RouterContext (created by Router)
        in Router (created by App)
        in div (created by App)
        in IntlProvider (created by IntlWrapper)
        in IntlWrapper (created by Connect(IntlWrapper))
        in Connect(IntlWrapper) (created by App)
        in Provider (created by App)
        in App
        in AppContainerprintWarning
```

and then:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of bound createElement.(…)
```

Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: How does Field component look like? I'd say your error message is pretty indicative: Field component adds props to <input> tag, which cannot be there.

Comment: @Maggie the page doesn't render, so I couldn't tell you. And, yes, I know what it's doing - but I clearly have no control over it, which isn't great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `component={input}` to `component="input"` . Same for `textarea` & `select`.

Comment: This might be correct. The docs for the new version 6.2.0 seem to suggest that that is the way, so maybe it's a docs error...